# Jasmine-marble/createSpy - Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Tags: angular, jasmine, jasmine-marbles

I am writing an jasmine-marble test for my functionality, everything works fine but cold observable created is not returned :
Following is the HTML code:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li *ngFor="let product of tempProductList; let i = index" id="{{'product_'+i}}" class="list-group-item">{{product.title }} <span class="badge">{{product.price}}</span></li>

  </ul>
```

Service method that returns data :

```
 public getProductList():Observable<any> {
       return interval(1000).pipe(
        take(PRODUCT_LIST.length),
        map(i => PRODUCT_LIST[i])
      );;
  }
```

Component method that gets the data :

```
 getProductData(){
    this.sub = this.marbaleTestService.getProductList().subscribe((products)=>{
      this.tempProductList = products;
    },
    (error) =>{
      this.isPresent = true;
    });
  }
```

In the given spec function, I am getting the error, in the it function error comes for liElement, but the real reason is that observable returned using the spy object always remains undefined.

```
fdescribe('MarbleTestComponent', () => {
  let component: MarbleTestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MarbleTestComponent>;
  let mSpy: jasmine.Spy;
  let mockList = mockProductList;

 beforeEach(() => {
  const marbleService = jasmine.createSpyObj('MarbleTestService', ['getProductList']);
  mSpy = marbleService.getProductList;

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MarbleTestComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: MarbleTestService, useValue: marbleService }]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MarbleTestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });


  it('[Marble - cold] - should list products after getProductList ', () => {

    let p$ = cold('p1-p2-p3|', { p1: mockList[0], p2: mockList[1], p3: mockList[2] });
    console.log(p$);
    ***mSpy.and.returnValue(p$);***

    component.getProductData();
    fixture.detectChanges();
   getTestScheduler().flush();
    fixture.detectChanges();


    expect(mSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();

     const liElement = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.list-group-item'));

    console.log(liElement.length);

    expect(liElement[0].nativeElement.innerText).toContain(mockList[0].title);
    expect(liElement[1].nativeElement.innerText).toContain(mockList[1].title);
    expect(liElement[2].nativeElement.innerText).toContain(mockList[2].title); 
  });

});
```

What I want to do is to get the observable created using cold() method and return it using the spy object created using createSpyObj function, but either observable is not returned to the calling function in component or there is some other issue.
I have spent hours looking for this one but have not found suitable answer or proper resolution.

Comment: What length do  you get when you console.log(liElement.length)

Comment: I get length value as 0

Comment: Before the .list-element-group item check if there is any condition that you are setting that makes the list not be visible

Comment: You also need to mock the observables that are return your data and give them some return value